# Docker Error: Cannot cerate container for service <container name>: status code not OK but 500

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I used docker-compose to create docker containers in my *React*, *Node.js*, and *Postgres* structured project.
After I created *Dockerfile* and *docker-compose.yml*, I did docker up 'docker-compose up --build.'
Then, I wasn't be able to create containers, and get an errors.
I get Error says:
[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piI3K.png)
[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKSWd.png)
[Error 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iG4l4.png)

How can I fix it and successfully build containers?

Here is a docker-compose.yml file in './'

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    container_name: mylivingcity_server
    build: ./server
    expose:
      - 3001
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    volumes:
      - ./server/config:/usr/src/app/server/config
      - ./server/controllers:/usr/src/app/server/controllers
      - ./server/db:/usr/src/app/server/db
    command: npm run start
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    container_name: mylivingcity_postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=mylivingcity
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  frontend:
    container_name: mylivingcity_frontend
    build: ./frontend
    expose:
      - 3000
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/src:/usr/src/app/frontend/src
      - ./frontend/public:/usr/src/app/frontend/public
    command: npm start
    stdin_open: true
```

Here is a Dockerfile in './frontend'

```
FROM node:12

# Create frontend directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/frontend/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/frontend/

# Install dependencies
COPY package*.json /usr/src/app/frontend/
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app/frontend/

CMD [ "npm" , "start" ]
```

Here is a Dockerfile in './server'

```
FROM node:12

# Create server directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/server/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/server/

# Install dependencies
COPY package*.json /usr/src/app/server/
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app/server/

CMD [ "npm" , "run" , "start" ]
```

Comment: Do you want to share your dockerfile and docker-compose.yml? They are probably related to your issue?

Comment: Sure @CharlesBamford

Comment: the docker-compose.yml is referencing files in ./server and ./frontent, but your post references ../frontend and ../server. Is this intentional?

Comment: No intention, It should be ./server ./frontend. With those right path I get those kind of errors. @CharlesBamford

Comment: It is related to docker in windows setup.
Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/60814428/5924504 it may help.