# Docker Message":"Unhandled exception: Filesharing has been cancelled"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, laradock

When I run docker I get error "ERROR: for mysql  Cannot create container for service mysql: status code not OK but 500: {"Message":"Unhandled exception: Filesharing has been cancelled",""

I add folder fith project and dockerDesctop/

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker Compose failed to build - Filesharing has been cancelled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60754297/docker-compose-failed-to-build-filesharing-has-been-cancelled)

Comment: I add all folders.  The error is still there.